# Remove single event handler from a user control

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

Say I have two user controls and I want to remove an event handler from one instance of the control.

To illustrate I've just made it a button as user control:

```
public partial class SuperButton : UserControl
{
public SuperButton()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;
}

private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
}
}
```

**I've added two super buttons to the form and I want to disable the MouseEnter event firing for SuperButton2.**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    superButton2.RemoveEvents<SuperButton>("EventMouseEnter");
}
}

public static class EventExtension
{
public static void RemoveEvents<T>(this Control target, string Event)
{
    FieldInfo f1 = typeof(Control).GetField(Event, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    object obj = f1.GetValue(target.CastTo<T>());
    PropertyInfo pi = target.CastTo<T>().GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    EventHandlerList list = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(target.CastTo<T>(), null);
    list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
}

public static T CastTo<T>(this object objectToCast)
{
    return (T)objectToCast;
}
}
```

The code runs but it doesn't work - the MouseEnter and Leave events still fire. I'm looking to do something like this:

superButton2.MouseEnter -= xyz.MouseEnter;

**Update:** Read this comments questions...

Comment: `superButton2.MouseEnter -= button1_MouseEnter` doesn't work?

Comment: I need to do it in the Form1, not in the user control. Unless hmmm

Comment: @lc - Put that as an answer can you. As in: `public void DisableEvent(){button1.MouseEnter -= button1_MouseEnter;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you don't need to remove *all* event handlers at once, just the specific one you're interested in. Use `-=` to remove a handler in the same way you use `+=` to add one:

```
button1.MouseEnter -= button1_MouseEnter;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just set `superButton2.MouseEnter = null;`? That should do the trick until somewhere `MouseEnter` is assigned a value.

Just for an update, another way to handle it, and perfectly legal :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestControls
{
    class SimpleButton:Button
    {
        public bool IgnoreMouseEnter { get; set; }

        public SimpleButton()
        {
            this.IgnoreMouseEnter = false;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("this.IgnoreMouseEnter = {0}", this.IgnoreMouseEnter);

            if (this.IgnoreMouseEnter == false)
            {
                base.OnMouseEnter(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fails to compile - 
`The eventt MouseEnter can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=`

Comment: This is terribly wrong. The C# compiler will not allow you to do this because there is a lot going on with multicast delegates/events that the += and -= are syntactic sugar for.

Comment: For the edit I am happy to get you back to zero +1. Simplifying the issue helped... its [disabling the To Treeview controls dynamic expanding/collapsing](http://superuser.com/questions/461374/record-directory-structure-change-migration) that withheld me seeing the solution